# Typescript type missmatch when creating external module

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am using TypeScript and creating an API using nestjs and typeorm. Some of the modules in the project are made reusable by extracting them into its own node module. This is causing the `Repository` type in the external module to not be the same type as the `Repository` type inside the original package. So when using the external module I get the error

```
Argument of type 'import("/Users/user/project/node_modules/typeorm/repository/Repository")
.Repository<import("/Users/project/src/user/user.entity").User>' 
is not assignable to parameter of type 
'import("/Users/user/my-module/node_modules/typeorm/repository/Repository")
.Repository<import("/Users/project/src/user/user.entity").User>'.
```

The typeorm package is listed as a peerDependency in the node package so it should always be the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your external library seems to have its own type definitions. In [this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/typescript/issues/6496#issuecomment-384786222), it is suggested to map imports to a folder under `node_modules` manually in your `package.json`:

```
"paths": {
  "typeorm": ["node_modules/typeorm"],
  "typeorm/*": ["node_modules/typeorm/*"]
}
```

This might only be an issue when using `npm link`.

Comment: Ops, that was actually a typo from me... the Repository is imported from different paths but not the User type.

Comment: Ah ok. :) Did you install your package from npm or did you use npm link?

Comment: I used npm link